# What do these skills do in Don't get fired?

Tags: dont-get-fired

I'm playing Don't get fired on Android and I came across some skills which I don't understand.

What do the skills "workload", "faster touch work" and "team work" do?

I tried to search on the Web but couldn't find anything...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workload increases the total amount of work that you can have at any time, ie you can have a bigger pile of "books"/work.

Faster touch work means that when you tap on yourself (and your team members, once you make Deputy General Manager,) the increase in work speed is faster.

Team work means that your team members (once you reach Assistant Manager) will complete their work faster.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a source for your answer?

Comment: @matan7890 Just my observations from playing the game.